# In Lua, how do you insert into a table with string keys?

Tags: lua, lua-table

In the command

```
table.insert(table, data)
```

how can you use that but for the inserts have string keys?

PSEUDO CODE

```
tableOfStuff = {cat, pig, hat, lemon}
t = {}
for i=1, #tableOfStuff do
    table.insert(t, key=tableOfStuff[i], data=tableOfStuff[i])
end
```

So I end up with a table...

```
t['cat'] == 'cat'
t['dog'] == 'dog' 
etc.....
```

***EDIT***

I think my example confused people... I am asking how to use "insert.table" but insert tings with string keys...

```
table.insert(table,data,stringkey)
```

something like this?

Comment: `t[tableOfStuff[i]] = tableOfStuff[i]`

Comment: so how do you do that for a big list?

Comment: `for _, key in ipairs(tableOfStuff) do t[key]=key end`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, but this is not really what I am asking.. sorry I am confusing people.... I put some new info in the main post under EDIT.

Comment: Can you explain why `for _, key in ipairs(tableOfStuff) do t[key]=key end` is not sufficient? As far as I can tell based on your edit, that is exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: Because i made that example as i thought it would explain myself. What about an example where we want to "insert" into a table but use strings... so have a table called "animals" and then I want to insert into it ['quad'] = 'cat'.. instead of [1]='Cat'... like how can you add to a table but use string keys?

Answer (score 2):

### Creating One Table

If all you want is to create a table with strings as keys, then check out [Table Constructors](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.7), you have a couple options.

Option 1:

```
t = { key1 = "value1", key2 = "value2" }

--or like this:

t = { ["key1"] = "value1", ["key2"] = "value2" }
```

Option 2: (create an empty table first)

```
t = {}

t.key1 = "value1"    

--or like this

t["key2"] = "value2"
```

It looks like you want the keys and values to be the same string and that is possible. Just write the same thing for key1 and value1. So `t["cat"] = "cat"`.

### Using Two Tables

Based on your example code, it looks like you want to take an existing table of strings and create from that a new table with strings as both the keys and the values. To do that:

```
table1 = { "cat", "pig", "hat", "lemon" }
table2 = {}
for i=1, #table1 do
    table2[ table1[i] ] = table1[i]
end

--test
print table2["cat"]
```

Here is a good lesson about tables in Lua: [Lua Tables Tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TablesTutorial)

Answer (score 0):

The comment is right.You needn't and you can't use table.insert.You can see the document [table.insert](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-table.insert).It's only support the number.It' used for the array part of table.But you're using the hash part of a table.

code:

```
tableOfStuff = {"cat", "pig", "hat", "lemon"}
t = {}
for i=1, #tableOfStuff do
    local szKey = tableOfStuff[i];
    t[szKey] = tableOfStuff[i]; -- the value can be the others.
end
```

Comment: So how can i add to a table, but use string keys?

Comment: I have give a simple code from yours.So the point is use the hash part of table : t[key] = value;